# Not understanding the answer to a fractional expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$\frac { 8r^{ 1/2 }s^{ -3 } }{ 2r^{ -2 }s^{ 4 } } $$

The first step I took was getting rid of the negative exponents:

$$\frac { 8r^{ 1/2 }2r^{ 2 } }{ s^{ 3 }s^{ 4 } } $$

Then I performed the multiplication in the numerator and denominator and got:

$$\frac { 16r^{ 5/2 } }{ s^{ 7 } } $$

Apparently, this is wrong. What mistake did I make?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to take the reciprocal of $2$ in the denominator. So, the answer is $4r^{5/2}/s^7$.

Comment: to take it? I did take it..

Comment: No, you just kicked the $2$ up to the numerator. Dividing by $2$ is multiplying by $1/2$, remember? $y/(2x)=\frac{1}{2}y/x$.

Comment: so you're saying I should've first divided $\frac { 8r^{ 1/2 } }{ 2r^{ -2 } } $ to get ${ 4r }^{ 1/2 }$ in the numerator and then moved the ${ r }^{ -2 }$ to the numerator?

Comment: Basically, yes. When moving $2r^{-2}$ from the denominator to the numerator, it becomes $\frac{1}{2}r^2$. Trust me, I've double checked my answer with Mathematica.

Comment: I believe you. I also have the answer. I was asking because I want to understand why I was wrong.

Comment: Always a good idea.